# I have an error in this command: sudo ./install

Tags: compilation, sudo, phalcon

I'm trying to install PhalconPHP by it's documentation. in the compilation step i have an error! When i Perform this command:

> sudo ./install

Error:

> 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I removed 'sudo' from this command and i have this error for './install'
please guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) is an application that temporarily allows you to gain administrative privileges so that you can install the application.

If you are trying to install Phalcon on your local machine which runs Linux, then you will need to either install sudo from your software manager or through the command line

1. Assume the root role using `su`
2. Install the application using `apt-get install sudo`

If you are trying this on a remote machine, then you need to either install sudo yourself or have the administrator of that machine do it.

Comment: I'm using windows8! Reportedly sudo work Only in linux! Can i install sudo in windows? How i run this command in windows?

Comment: If you are using Windows then all you need to do is download the DLL from the download page, enable it in your php.ini configuration, and restart your web server. No need for sudo ;)